# Multiple request at android volley

Tags: android, json, android-studio, request, android-volley

I get an error when I make multiple volley requests.
First, I am requesting login and it works fine. After the login process, the main activity opens in the application. When I make a new request here, the request is added to the queue. But the request is not executed. what is the reason of this?

This code is login function:

```
private void LoginUser(final String email, final String password) {

    String tag_string_req = "request_register";

    pDialog.setMessage("Giriş Yapılıyor ...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                if (!error) {
                    JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                    int userId = user.getInt("UserId");
                    int uId = user.getInt("UId");


                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("UserId", userId);
                    intent.putExtra("UId", uId);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("message");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    hideDialog();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);

            return params;
        }

    };
    strReq.setShouldCache(false);
    LoginApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}
```

This code is get datas about user at after login function:

```
public void Sync(final Context context, final int uId)
{
    String tag_string_req = "request_syncUser";
    db1 = new Database(context);

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            //gelen tüm verileri local db ye at
            try {
                SQLiteDatabase db = db1.getWritableDatabase();
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray responseUser = jObj.getJSONArray("user");
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                String message = jObj.getString("message");
                if(!error) {
                    for(int i=0; i<responseUser.length(); i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject user = responseUser.getJSONObject(i);

                        String u_name = user.getString("Name");
                        String u_surname = user.getString("Surname");
                        String u_email = user.getString("Email");
                        String u_password = user.getString("Password");
                        String u_isLogin = user.getString("isLogin");
                        String u_isSync = user.getString("isSync");
                        int u_uId = user.getInt("UId");

                        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                        cv.put("Name", u_name);
                        cv.put("Surname", u_surname);
                        cv.put("Email", u_email);
                        cv.put("Password", u_password);
                        cv.put("isLogin", u_isLogin);
                        cv.put("isSync", u_isSync);
                        cv.put("UId", u_uId);

                        db.insertOrThrow("user", null, cv);

                        Toast.makeText(context, message ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Toast.makeText(context, u_name + u_surname,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } else {

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(context, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("uId", String.valueOf(uId));

            return params;
        }
    };
    strReq.setShouldCache(false);
    LoginApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}
```

}

Comment: Post your code and the error you get

Comment: edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

Well we need to see your code?

That said my guess is you are not creating / accessing your queue in a singleton pattern. Complete guess. Always always always post code.